# How to find out the mysql service on linux server

Tags: mysql, linux

How to find out the mysql service on linux server.

I have tried it .

```
[root@anjum/]# service mysqld status
mysqld: unrecognized service

[root@anjum/]# service mysql status
mysql: unrecognized service
 service mysql status
mysql: unrecognized service
```

Comment: I have checked the overlalll service runing on my server using <code>service --status-all</code> and it show multipathd is stopped
<code>..... munin-node is stopped
mysqld (pid 5163) is running...
mysqld (pid 5163) is running...
mysqld (pid 5163) is running...
netconsole module not loaded
netplugd is stopped
..
</code>

Comment: show results of ps -aux | grep mysql

Answer (score 3):

Just remember if you are using MySQL via a docker container (say maybe MySQL:8.0) then in many of the images you will not have the service management utilities to do this.

> `service mysqld status` or `service mysql status` will give you `unrecognized service` even though the service is running fine and you can log into the MySQL prompt using `mysql -uroot -p` and start executing queries without any problems.

This has to do with the way that the docker container was set up, to keep the container as small as possible. If for some reason you want to restart mysql, then the standard way would be to restart the container.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that mysql is installed on your server by below steps-

Step1:

```
cat /etc/my.cnf
```

get data directory from here suppose it is /var/lib/mysql

Step2: check if all related mysql files are there-

```
ls -lh /var/lib/mysql
```

You can also check by below command:

```
ls /etc/init.d | grep mysql
```

If everything is ok and still showing unrecognized. Then you have to check if same ip alloted to some other server.

Comment: its worked for me .I have used third step  ls /etc/init.d | grep mysql then result receive with name of service . In my case <code>mysqld mysqld_master</code>

Comment: >>  Can you please give me guidance on this . My Databases are located on different directory in like /db_data/master/ <code>[root@anjum /]# mysqldump -u root -ppassword rt3 > /db_data/replica_rt.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect</code> Table are innodb  so Dump is mandatory How i can resolve this issue

Comment: 1) execute "mysql -uroot -p" and check if you are able to connect mysql,   2) check if you are able to connect your db from outside either sqlyog, mysqladmin etc. and share output to check the issue.

Comment: When i have execute step on command then the this error shows ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)  . And I am using navicate and phpmyadmin. i am able to connect using these tools but database is heavy and size is in GB's. so want to connect create dump using command

Comment: One more thing my.cnf file is <code>[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 4M
.....</code>  but i can see my databases are originally located on  this path /db_data/master/

Comment: Problem is this i am working on live server . i want to this activity without down time . should i add datadir=/db_data/master  in my.cnf  ?

Comment: either you are checking wrong cnf or someone change cnf after mysql start as it is showing different data dir than actual...please check your data-dir by "show global variables like 'datadir';

Comment: also check if mysql.sock file exist at /var/lib/mysql folder and mysql has permission to read it.

Comment: There is  two my.cnf file and both address are  /etc/my.cnf
/root/.my.cnf. I have checked no permission issue on both folder. and exact location are defined in /root/.my.cnf .File content is [mysqladmin]
socket=/db_data/master/mysql.sock(Exact location that system are using). i have also changed the file name of etc/my.cnf... and restarted the service then observ that everything is worked fine with /root/.my.cnf  this file

Comment: i have also change the socket=/db_data/master/mysql.sock  in /etc/my.cnf then same error.

Comment: cnf will be /etc/my.cnf not /root/my.cnf...do one thing in /etc/my.cnf data directory should be as your data directory physically, and keep sock file path as giving erro,  then stop mysql service, check if any mysql process is running by ps -aux | grep mysql, hope there will not be any process related with mysql, then start mysql service then try....

Comment: I have checked with this command ps -aux | grep mysql..  and result is <code>ps -aux | grep mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my_master.cnf --datadir=/db_data/master --socket=/db_data/master/mysql.sock
mysql     4977  5.9  4.0 850568 165608 ?       Sl   Aug12  52:27 ......</code>
By adding  -h 127.0.0.1   in command my issue is resolved . Thanks @ZafarMalik you helped me lot.

Comment: if it helped you then give it a green stick... :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like MySQL has not been installed there.

Check that:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

returns something like

```
mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
```